# Option delta - Conditional probability definition?

Tags: options, probability, delta

Can someone help me interpret this definition of delta?

> Delta is a conditional probability of terminal value (St) being greater than the Strike (X) given that St > X for a call option.

Is the second part of the statement not completely redundant? This may be completely obvious, but I don't see why this is conditional.

The source of the definition is:

Initially found here, where three definitions are given:

> https://financetrainingcourse.com/education/2012/09/sales-trading-interview-guide-understanding-greeks-option-delta-and-gamma/

Also in:

> Farid (2015) - An Option Greeks Primer: Building Intuition with Delta Hedging and Monte Carlo Simulation in Excel.

Comment: where is this definition take from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO the 'definition' you mention is not a mathematical definition *per se*, but rather an approximation used by some practitioners.

Mathematically, it is $N(d_2)$ in the BS formula which figures the conditional probability that the terminal asset price $S_T$ will finish above the strike level $X$ given the information we possess today (represented by $S_t$), and that, **under a risk-neutral measure** which uses the risk-free money market account as numéraire. Omitting discounting, $N(d_2)$ is indeed the price of a binary or digital option assuming GBM.

The delta (omitting dividend payments) is on the other hand given by $N(d_1)$ not $N(d_2)$. Only for extremely short time to maturity or low volatility can $d_1$ be approximated by $d_2$ and hence $\Delta$ be approximated by $N(d_2)$ (again assuming no divs).

Still, we could also say that $\Delta$ corresponds to a probability of finishing in the money, but in **an equivalent martingale measure which uses the asset itself as numéraire**.

It therefore depends on the probability measure in which you are working/interpreting your results. In the sell-side we like to think in terms of risk-neutral probabilities (or binary options).

See the definition of $d_1$ and $d_2$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)) for instance.

Comment: So what you say seems to be right, look at [this](http://www.timworrall.com/fin-40008/bscholes.pdf). The prob ending in the money is $N(d_2)$ and $N(d_1)$ is more complicated.

Comment: @Richard But you are right too: $N(d_1)$ is indeed the probability of finishing in the money under an EMM which uses the asset $S_t$ itself as numéraire instead of the risk-free money market account $B_t$. It is worth noting that both these conditional probabilities of finishing ITM will be different from the 'true' one attached to the physical measure $\mathbb{P}$ so it is merely a question of interpretation and terminology.